# alert message that checkbox is unchecked using php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am looking for a way to tell the user that he must select at least on checkbox if he press the submit button without selecting any checkbox. by using php

Comment: it sounds like javascript is better for what you want

Comment: You could use front end validation to achieve this easily, maybe not necessary to involve server side script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
        $checked=0;
        for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){//check all the boxes
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'.$i]))
                $checked=1;
        }
   }

    if ($checked==0){//alert if no boxes are checked
        echo("You must check at least 1");
    }
    else{
        header("location: nextpage.php");
    }

?>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
      <input name="checkbox0" type="checkbox" value="1"> 1
      <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="2"> 2
      <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="3"> 3
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: the code works fine but when I make the action equal to another php page it will takes me to this page even if I didn't select the checkbox.

Comment: you should set the action to this processing page, then if the $checked value is 0 use a header to go to the page you wish to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @jm-verastigue answer redirecting the user to the page you want to:

```
if ($checked == 0){
// display alert
} else {
// redirect user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP happens on the server, before the user sees the page. The user only sees the final rendered product. You can use javascript to test that your element is selected before they leave the page, or test it on the next page, where your form is handled. (or do both because javascript can be turned off by the user.)

The beginning of the JS you're looking for is `onsubmit()` and maybe `document.getElementByID['the id of the input field'].checked`

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jquery for this and do it like so...

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="wherever.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="test" value="Checkbox1">Checkbox1
<button id="formsubmit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Then in your Jquery, do

```
$('#formsubmit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    if($("#checkbox1").is(':checked')){
    //on success
    $('form#test').submit();
    } else { 
   //on no checkbox
   alert('you need to check  box');
   }
   });
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uT3Vc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in **PHP**, you can do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])) //checking if form was submitted
{
    if( isset($_POST['test'] )) //checking if button was checked
    {
    echo "Checkbox was checked!"; 
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="value">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
```

This will check if the form was submitted or not, and then checks if the checkbox was checked. If it was, then it just echoes the message. Pretty simple.

Hope this helps.